# MySQL - update text using wildcard in WordPress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to update some links in my database that look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Accelerator_Oil.pdf</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Accelerator_Oil.pdf</a>
```

And I need to replace the text with 'View PDF' (without the quotes) whilst keeping the href so that they look like this

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">View PDF</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">View PDF</a>
```

Here is my wild stab in the dark - very new to MySQL

```
UPDATE `ayfryvrxb2_postmeta` SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '.pdf">%%</a>', '.pdf">View PDF</a>"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql command it works for me

```
SELECT  REPLACE('<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Accelerator_Oil.pdf</a>',


      ( SUBSTR('<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Accelerator_Oil.pdf</a>',
      (LOCATE('.pdf">', '<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Accelerator_Oil.pdf</a>') + 6),
      LOCATE('.pdf</a>', '<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Accelerator_Oil.pdf</a>')) )
      ,'View PDF</a>'
      )

FROM your_table h
```

BUT you must replace my hard coded string `<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Action_K_Salts.pdf">http://www.domain.com.au/PDF/Rapidvite/Accelerator_Oil.pdf</a>` with your table column. For examle if you column with these links names `my_table_links`

then the final sql query will be like bellow

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(my_table_links,


      ( SUBSTR(my_table_links,
      (LOCATE('.pdf">', my_table_links) + 6),
      LOCATE('.pdf</a>', my_table_links)) )
      ,'View PDF</a>'
       )

FROM `my_table` h
```

And finaly in update case it will be

```
UPDATE `ayfryvrxb2_postmeta` SET 

meta_value =  REPLACE(meta_value,


          ( SUBSTR(meta_value,
          (LOCATE('.pdf">', meta_value) + 6),
          LOCATE('.pdf</a>', meta_value)) )
          ,'View PDF</a>'
           )
where 1;
```

Comment: It works for me. Which are your strings? maybe you must change the number 6. Try with select first and send me the results

Answer (score 0):

I use - and it's not necessarily the best way, but it works for my sites when I move from concept to live or whatever - this:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`, '<OLD URL'>, <'NEW URL'>;
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, '<OLD URL'>, <'NEW URL'>;
```

Apologies if I've left a syntax error in, but hopefully you get the gist of what I do.  The second command is useful if you may have links in custom fields, which I use a lot.